# Rhytmbox alternative for built-in tags

Tags: rhythmbox, tag

I have tracks in formats that either not supported for tagging in Rhytmbox or don't have any tagging support at all and I want to scrobble them, which, naturally, requires at least artist and track name.

Is there a way to "tag locally" in Rhytmbox's playlist independently of actual physical format, so it will keep information, display it and report it to scrobbling and other plugins?

Answer (score 1):

Any "tags" you set in Rhythmbox, are not set in the files themselves, but only in the library database of Rhythmbox. You can simply right click on any song in your library, choose `Properties`, and edit the title and artist for the track. This will save the values in the Rhythmbox database, and the `audioscrobbler` plug-in should use those values to post them to last.fm or libre.fm.

Comment: That'd be exactly what I want, but unfortunately it doesn't really work that way. Right-clicking, selecting properties, entering values and hitting close on song from .aac file produces "Error while saving song information. GStreamer encountered a general stream error."